# SQL Server Data Tools: One or more issues caused a failure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a problem to install SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT), I get the following error:
`One or more issues caused the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup.`

Bellow I added the log file.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0baRS5dYAX_U0RibGhGd19qVnc/view?usp=sharing

I have Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2012. I installed SSDT is from this page - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501 - SSDT in Visual Studio 2015

Can anyone help with this cause?

Comment: Please post the exact error message here, we're not going to look through whole of the log file to search for you error.. Are you planning on using SSIS on SQL Server 2012? Then you should not be using VS 2015 for that (have a look [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/12a7e5b7-249f-43ef-b6c5-3f98e136e0cf/ssis-and-visual-studio-versions?forum=sqlintegrationservices)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The failure is due to the VS2015 Isolated shell returning an error. You can run this yourself and see if it succeeds (in which case SSDT install should proceed OK) or fails, in which case you should see a good error message.

To get the shell installer run "SSDTSetup.exe /layout" from the command line. This will copy all dependencies onto your machine in a payload folder beside the setup installer. You can then run the vs_isoshell.exe installer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Install 'VS_ISOSHELL.exe' first. You can find it in the directory PAYLOAD/X86.
After the installation run SSDTSETUPD.exe. It should be working properly now.

Comment: Where is that directory?

Comment: It's a while I ago I had this issue but if i recall correctly the folder payload can be find in the zip folder with all the other files that you have downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

User MLGuy's answer solved it for me:  Disable IE Enhanced Security Configuration and rerun the installer.

[SQL Server Data Tools 2015 installation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000781/sql-server-data-tools-2015-installation-error)