# SQL Server Data Tools 2015 installation error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2014, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to install SQL Server Data Tools - Visual Studio 2015, but I keep getting an "Unspecified error".

The log file is at https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3CEKzS2Sw8OODNJOXZJVGRWQlU.

I already have Visual Studio Professional 2015 installed.

I want to install SSDT 2015 because my databases were recently migrated from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2014, and I need to use SSIS.  Previously, I used SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio to create my DTS packages, which I still have installed to access old packages.

I've tried to find a resolution to my problem but everything seems to be about VS 2013 installation issues.

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Here's the relevant section from the linked log file.

```
[2308:24BC][2016-10-12T09:32:14]: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[2308:24BC][2016-10-12T09:32:14]: Apply begin
[287C:2C64][2016-10-12T09:32:14]: Creating a system restore point.
[287C:2C64][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Created a system restore point.
[287C:2C64][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\.be\SSDTSetup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\SSDTSetup.exe'
[287C:2C64][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Registering bundle dependency provider: {2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}, version: 14.0.60923.0
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Prompt for source of package: DotNet46, payload: DotNet46, path: U:\Downloads\Microsoft\SSDT\SSDT 2015\payload\neutral\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS.exe
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Acquiring package: DotNet46, payload: DotNet46, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689' to: 'C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\DotNet46'
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689' to working path: 'C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\DotNet46'
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Failed to acquire payload: DotNet46 to working path: C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\DotNet46, error: 0x80072ee7.
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Applied non-vital package: DotNet46, encountered error: 0x80072ee7. Continuing...
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Prompt for source of package: adalsql13X64, payload: adalsql13X64, path: U:\Downloads\Microsoft\SSDT\SSDT 2015\payload\x64\adalsql.msi
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Acquiring package: adalsql13X64, payload: adalsql13X64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\adalsql13X64'
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817285&clcid=0x409' to working path: 'C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\adalsql13X64'
[2308:28AC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Failed to acquire payload: adalsql13X64 to working path: C:\Users\JENMCC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\adalsql13X64, error: 0x80072ee7.
[287C:2500][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Removing cached package: DotNet46, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\
[287C:2500][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Unable to remove cached package: DotNet46, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\83D048D171FF44A3CAD9B422137656F585295866\, reason: 0x80070003. Continuing...
[2308:24BC][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Error 0x80072ee7: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[287C:2C64][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Removed bundle dependency provider: {2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}
[287C:2C64][2016-10-12T09:32:21]: Removing cached bundle: {2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{2e9e05c8-ae49-4af6-9121-fa821d1b5334}\
[2308:24BC][2016-10-12T09:32:22]: Apply complete, result: 0x80072ee7, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
```

Comment: It seems you had network issues at that moment in time,logs quote this `Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=715689`

Comment: Links are considered bad on SO, instead post the relevant parts of the link in the question.

Comment: @pingul You are right. I pasted the relevant section from the linked log file.

Comment: @pingul: I wasn't sure what was relevant and tried to paste the entire log but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: @TheGameiswar: I tried the install several times but received the same errors, even though I was able to browse to the mentioned links.

Comment: Even though the log showed

    'Failed to send request to URL...'

I was able to manually go to the specified URL in the web browser.  I downloaded the missing items and ran the install again.  This time, install gave me a new URL that it couldn't request. So I download that item and tried again. The third time, it came up with another failed request.  Again, I downloaded the missing item...I ended up downloading 20+ items before the SSDT 2015 installation completed successfully.
I downloaded the installation file from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501, so it should have worked.

Comment: @J.McCarthy I'm glad you got it working. You should add your procedure as an answer and accept it, so other people stumbling on this post can find and try out your solution themselves.

Answer (score 18):

neera's answer did not worked form me. Another possible solution to the connection problem ('Failed to send request to URL') is to install SSDT from a .iso, but this is not trivial when working in a virtual machine.

**Diagnosis**: During the installation process of SSDT, a few components are supposed to be downloaded (i.e. the link in your log file represents one of those). Your virtual machine attempts to download such files through Internet Explorer (IE). However, by default the IE Enhanced Security Option is enabled. As a result, this stops you from downloading the required tools.

**Solution**: Log in your virtual machine, launch "Server Manager", select "Local Server" on the left, turn off "IE Enhanced Security Configuration".

Comment: Such a simple error costs so much time. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same problem on a 2016 server. I moved the install to the root directory and ran as administrator Also had to disabled IE enhanced security configuration. After that the install worked Fine.

Answer (score 3):

The error is unable to send request, so you can try install with offline. Here is the detail:
"An ISO image of SSDT can be used as an alternative way to install SSDT or to set up an Administrative Installation point."
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501

Answer (score 2):

just try -- Run as administrator instead of clicking straight away

Answer (score 0):

Through a very tedious process, I successfully installed SSDT 2015.

Even though the log showed:

```
 Failed to send request to URL...
```

I was able to manually go to the specified URL in the web browser, so I downloaded the missing items and ran the install again. This time, install gave me a new URL that it couldn't request. So I download that item and tried again. The third time, it came up with another failed request. Again, I downloaded the missing item...

Overall, I ended up downloading 25+ items before the SSDT 2015 installation completed successfully. Using the URLs referenced in the log, I manually download the following files and put them in the directories shown in the log file.

```
 adalsql.msi
 CommonAzureTools.cab
 CommonAzureTools.msi
 NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS.exe
 SharedManagementObjects.msi
 SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi
 SQL_AS_AMO.msi
 SQL_AS_AMO2012.msi
 SQL_AS_AMO2014.msi
 SQL_AS_OLEDB.msi
 SqlDom.msi
 SqlLocalDB.msi
 sqlncli.msi
 SQLSysClrTypes.msi
 SSDT.msi
 SSDTAS.msi
 SSDTDBSvcExternals.msi
 SSDTIS.msi
 SSDTPostInstall.msi
 SSDTRS.msi
 SSISOneDesigner2012.msi
 SSISOneDesigner2014.msi
 TSqlLanguageService.msi
 vsta_ls.exe
 vsta_setup.exe
```

After each download and restart of the SSDT install, the progress would get a little bit more advanced before erroring out with another file it couldn't download.

FYI, I downloaded the installation file from msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501, so it should have worked.

Comment: What did you download from there? The web installer or the ISO? Most likely you have a network problem that results in timeouts

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering.  I just clicked the big blue "Download SQL Server Data Tools" link near the top. This took me to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=828740, which had me download and install SSDTSetup.exe.

Comment: That's the web installer that downloads files as needed. If you have network problems you will encounter errors. You can download an ISO from the same page

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me based on what John Altamura wrote in: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/246732/ssdt-1560-installer-the-configuration-registry-key.html

I uninstalled my SSDT using Visual Studio installer
I uninstalled Visual Studio using the Visual Studio installer
I then went to Add or Remove Programs and uninstalled everything that looked like it was related to Visual Studio
Then I had to actually re-download the VS installer from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/, as I needed the InstallCleanup.exe program in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\". This step is only needed if you uninstall VS Installer before running Installcleanup.exe.
Run InstallCleanup.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\"
Uninstall VS Installer from Add or Remove Programs.
Then to be safe I deleted this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
Then I restarted my PC.
Download Visual Studio 2017 from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ Just in case I performed a minimal install from VS Installer, of only installing a single language pack
Then download SSDT from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017 and install Then, it all worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

ISO image for SSDT is 1GB (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx) and it can be unaffordable for some VMs, but it really works, you can install it without internet access.

But, the error mentioned in the question was simply a connection issue and I used to solve it from MLguy solution. I'm using Windows Server 2012 Datacenter Build Server and IE Enhanced Security Configuration was blocking the downloads required for SSDT installation. I turned off IE Enhanced Security Configuration and installation was successful.

I wouldn't recommend disabling any other security feature. And yes, it would be better to turn IE Enhanced Security Configuration on after installation is completed.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to see the log file in the following location:

```
C:\xxx\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ActivityLog.xml
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The OP already knows where to find the log file **and has supplied the information from it in the question itself**.

Answer (score -1):

Disable Security programs. I had to allow all network traffic from F-secure Client security to make this setup to work.