# Failure on SSDT-BI Setup

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, ssdt-bi

Don't know if this is the right place for this but here it goes.

I'm trying to install SSDT on a Azure VM with Visual Studio installed, but I have had no luck. It runs for about 5 seconds, then sends me to the log file. The log file looks like:

> 40:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:07]: Prompt for source of package: SQLLOCALDBX64, payload: SQLLOCALDBX64, path: C:\Users\pddsadmin\Downloads\payload\x64\SqlLocalDB.msi
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:07]: Acquiring package: SQLLOCALDBX64, payload: SQLLOCALDBX64, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=824665&clcid=0x409
>   [28CC:3D08][2017-03-27T16:27:10]: Verified acquired payload: SQLLOCALDBX64 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\SQLLOCALDBX64, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{9B5F46D7-66AE-4796-B563-CA909FE87D4B}v13.0.2151.0\payload\x64\SqlLocalDB.msi.
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:10]: Prompt for source of package: SSDT14, payload: SSDT14, path: C:\Users\pddsadmin\Downloads\ssdt\x86\SSDT.msi
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:10]: Acquiring package: SSDT14, payload: SSDT14, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=832314&clcid=0x409
>   [28CC:3D08][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Verified acquired payload: SSDT14 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\SSDT14, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{22EDFCC2-E067-4E64-AFEA-30E84DD0EEA0}v14.0.61021.0\ssdt\x86\SSDT.msi.
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, path: C:\Users\pddsadmin\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Acquiring package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\PDDSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\SQLASADOMD'
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:12]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, path: C:\Users\pddsadmin\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Acquiring package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\PDDSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\SQLASADOMD'
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:15]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, path: C:\Users\pddsadmin\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Acquiring package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\PDDSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\SQLASADOMD'
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:18]: Prompt for source of package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, path: C:\Users\pddsadmin\Downloads\payload\x86\SQL_AS_ADOMD.msi
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Acquiring package: SQLASADOMD, payload: SQLASADOMD, download from: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to send request to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to connect to URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to get size and time for URL: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed attempt to download URL: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409' to: 'C:\Users\PDDSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\SQLASADOMD'
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed to acquire payload from: 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409' to working path: 'C:\Users\PDDSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\SQLASADOMD'
>   [3440:1868][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Failed to acquire payload: SQLASADOMD to working path: C:\Users\PDDSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\SQLASADOMD, error: 0x80072f08.
>   [28CC:3D08][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Removing cached package: SSDT14, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{22EDFCC2-E067-4E64-AFEA-30E84DD0EEA0}v14.0.61021.0\
>   [28CC:3D08][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Removing cached package: SQLLOCALDBX64, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{9B5F46D7-66AE-4796-B563-CA909FE87D4B}v13.0.2151.0\
>   [3440:04A4][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Error 0x80072f08: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
>   [28CC:2044][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Removed bundle dependency provider: {36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}
>   [28CC:2044][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Removing cached bundle: {36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{36239e0f-231f-49d5-a687-0ea260558484}\
>   [3440:04A4][2017-03-27T16:27:21]: Apply complete, result: 0x80072f08, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

From what I can tell it looks like it cant connect to the URL `https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=817266&clcid=0x409`. But when I open a browser and navigate to that URL directly, it downloads the exe with no problem.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

Comment: Are you opening the browser on the VM, or your local machine?

Comment: @alroc, I'm opening on the VM

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Data Tools 2015 installation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000781/sql-server-data-tools-2015-installation-error)

Answer (score 1):

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d1bfeabf-d37d-4748-b768-2802378f59ef/error-installing-ssdt?forum=ssdt

The installer can't download, a workaround is to download the iso and install from that, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Diagnosis**: During the installation process of SSDT, a few components must are supposed to be downloaded (i.e. the links in your log file represents one of those). Your virtual machine attempts to download such files through Internet Explorer (IE). However, by default the IE Enhanced Security Option is enabled. As a result, this stops you from downloading the required tools.

**Solution**: Log in your virtual machine, launch "Server Manager", select "Local Server" on the right, turn off "IE Enhanced Security Configuration".

I guess that your issue is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000781/sql-server-data-tools-2015-installation-error/43743812#43743812) one